# Tabularray - "Package tabularray Warning: Table width is too small, need 5.6181pt more!" & Text missing from cell

Tags: tables, tabularray

I am getting the error "Package tabularray Warning: Table width is too small, need 5.6181pt more!", which gave little results when searching for. I have previosly used the package without problem.

Also, the text "Fixed" does not appear in my table. Could this be connected to the error, or is something else wrong?

See the code and a screenshot of the table below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption = {The three different terminal models currently avaliable}
    ]{
      colspec={cccc},
      row{1}={font=\bfseries},
      hlines,
      vlines
    }
        & Standard & {High \\ Performance} & {Flat High \\ Performance} \\
        Antenna & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Electronic Phased Array \\
        Antenna size & 513x303mm & \SetCell[c=2]{c} 575x511mm \\
        Orientation & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Motorized Self Orienting} & Fixed \\
        Environmental rating & IP54 & \SetCell[c=2]{c} IP56 \\
        Snow Melt Capability & {Up to 40mm / hour} & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Up to 75mm / hour} \\
        Operating temperature & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {$-30^\circ C$ to $50^\circ C$} \\
        Field of View & $100^\circ$ & \SetCell[c=2]{c} $140^\circ$ \\
        Average Power Usage & 50-75W & \SetCell[c=2]{c} 110-150W \\
        Other & & & {Wind rating: \\ Survivable: 280 kph+} \\

    \end{talltblr}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Comment: You can find the reason by `\usepackage{showframe}`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you might want to have a look into the `siunitx` package to get proper spacing between your numbers and units and it might also be a good idea to have a look at the `\times` macro so you can stop abusing `x` as multiplication symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use only `c` columns in your table. This type of columns gets its width from the content. In the end your content is wider than the available text width, thus you get this warning. To avoid this, you can use at least one `X` column so that tabularray can resize the table to fit in the available text width.

"Fixed" is not visible in your table, because you placed it in the cell directly after a multicolumn cell, which is going to be merged with the cell before it. You need to add one more `&` after the multicolumn cell so that the `Fixed` is placed in the cell after the two merged cells.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray} 

\begin{document}
       \begin{table}[htbp]
       \centering
       \begin{talltblr}[
           caption = {The three different terminal models currently avaliable}
       ]{
         colspec={XXXX},
         columns={halign=c},
         row{1}={font=\bfseries},
         hlines,
         vlines
       }
           & Standard & {High \\ Performance} & {Flat High \\ Performance} \\
           Antenna & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Electronic Phased Array \\
           Antenna size & 513x303mm & \SetCell[c=2]{c} 575x511mm \\
           Orientation & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Motorized Self Orienting} & &Fixed \\
           Environmental rating & IP54 & \SetCell[c=2]{c} IP56 \\
           Snow Melt Capability & {Up to 40mm / hour} & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Up to 75mm / hour} \\
           Operating temperature & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {$-30^\circ C$ to $50^\circ C$} \\
           Field of View & $100^\circ$ & \SetCell[c=2]{c} $140^\circ$ \\
           Average Power Usage & 50-75W & \SetCell[c=2]{c} 110-150W \\
           Other & & & {Wind rating: \\ Survivable: 280 kph+} \\
   
       \end{talltblr}
     \end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your fix for "Fixed" missing worked - Thank you :)
I am still getting the same error about the table width. I did not quite understand your reason for the error, as the content in for ex. the last column is narrower than the space it has been given, so it should have just shrunk a bit more(?).

Comment: @QualZy You're welcome!

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I got to write the full comment - See my edited comment above

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a compilable example? Without knowing what class and packages you use, it is hard to reproduce the exact same page geometry as you have

Comment: Updated the original post now. The whole document is based upon a large template, so I might have missed out on something(?)

Comment: @QualZy The code in your question won't compile as it is missing the float package for the `[H]` option. If I replace your c columns with `X` columns, I don't get any warning about the table being too small.

Comment: And as for "the last column is narrower than the space it has been given, so it should have just shrunk a bit more": your last column can't shrink more or the `Survivable: 280 kph+` won't fit

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. I had another table which also gave me the same error - which I discovered by the help in the comment from @Clara. (As far as I could see, the error did not state linenumber).

Comment: @QualZy The warning about the resulting overfull box will tell you the line numbers https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmabK.png

Comment: Not on Overleaf, as far as I can tell(?) https://i.imgur.com/o1ubNjl.png

Comment: @QualZy Look at the full log file, not these short snippets overleaf shows you https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByLSJ.png

Answer (score 1):

- Why you use `talltblr` table? Do will latter add some table note (`\TblrNote{...}`)? If not, is better to use `tblr` table and move caption before table (after `\begin{table}`)
- The simplest way, that table fit in textarea, table should has at least one column of `X` type.
- For default `article` page layout column table tent to be wider than `\textwidth`. O it is sensible to reduce font size in table (to `\small`) and make different width of column.
- In MWE are for quantities used `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{The three different terminal models currently available}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ X[0.8, l, m] *{2}{X[c, m]} X[1.2, c, m] },
             colsep=3pt,
             row{1}={font=\bfseries},
            hlines, vlines
            }
    &   Standard
            &   High Performance
                    &   Flat High Performance       \\
Antenna
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Electronic Phased Array
            &       &                               \\
Antenna size
    &   \qtyproduct{513x303}{mm}
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} \qtyproduct{575x511}{mm}
                    &                               \\
Orientation
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Motorized Self Orienting
            &   Fixed
                    &                               \\
Environmental rating
    &   IP54
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    IP56
                    &                               \\
Snow Melt Capability
    &   Up to \qty{40}{\milli\metre\per\hour}
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}  \qty{75}{\milli\metre\per\hour} Up
                    &                               \\
Operating temperature
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  \qtyrange{-30}{50}{\degreeCelsius}
            &       &                               \\
Field of View
    &   \qty{100}{\degreeCelsius}
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \qty{140}{\degreeCelsius}
                    &                               \\
Average Power Usage
    &   \qtyrange{50}{75}{\watt}
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  \qtyrange{110}{150}{\watt}
                    &                               \\
Other
    &       &       &   Wind rating: Survivable: \qty{280}{kph+}
                                                    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: With talltblr I have the option to add footnotes, which I did in another table that I copied to make this one. Did not understand what you ment with your last point regarding MWE, but I have changed the units to use the siunitx-package.

Comment: @QualZy, sorry, I do not understand to what you like to tell me with your comment. If you not like to have just `tblr`, than simple replace it with `talltblr`. About this your question is unclear ...